# Parse.com user log out while offline

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, offline, logout

Here's the issue I have.
I am using Parse.com to build an app with login/logout functionality.
I have no issue implementing PFUser.logOut() when the device is connected to the network.
My issue is when the user is offline. I want to be able to log them out even when there's no internet connection.
So far I've tried to delete sessions from localDatastore and to unpin PFUser.currentUser()?.unpinInBackground(). None of those worked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to logout like this:

```
PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({ (error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()?.username = nil
    }
})
```

To check if the user is logged in with this solution, you need to check his username:

```
if let _ = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
    //The user is logged in
    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLoggedViewController", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a nice idea, but Parse SDK says:
"'Can't remove the 'username' field of a PFUser.'"

Comment: My log shows only network error : `[Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0) [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.966949 seconds.` but nothing about he can't remove the username field of PFUser...

Comment: If you leave it for as long as it takes to try all the attempts, then does it show an error?

Comment: it looks like Parse makes 4 attempts to connect to the network (time intervals are random, maybe 15/30 seconds to go to the last attempt)

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I'm trying to avoid... I don't want the user hanging for half a minute to log out. Otherwise, if after that you connect and open the app, Parse remembers to logout :D

Comment: That log messages appear just in the console. Users won't see anything. I use this method in my app, i work perfectly ;)

Comment: The logout is called in background, users won't have to wait a second to logout

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you **must** be connected to Internet to perform logout. It's not explicitly mentioned in docs though.